# Returning a set of records in C

Tags: c, postgresql

Based on the PostgreSQL 9.6 documentation, I'm trying to execute a function that returns set of records. Follow the code in C:

```
#include <funcapi.h>
 .....

FuncCallContext *funcctx; /*help control to save and remember state */
  MemoryContext oldcontext, newcontext;
  Datum result;
  uint32 ct_call;
  TupleDesc tupdesc;
  AttInMetadata *attinmeta;

  // struct line_reverse_tuple_args *args; /*aux struct for save state*/

  // struct geo_linestring *line1;
  // struct geo_linestring *line2;

  elog(NOTICE, "is being called called");

  /* Determine if the function is being called for the first time.*/
  if(SRF_IS_FIRSTCALL())
  {
    elog(NOTICE, "geo_linestring_intersection_points_v1 first called");

    /* initialize the FuncCallContext */
    funcctx = SRF_FIRSTCALL_INIT();

    /* switch to memory context appropriate for multiple function calls */
    newcontext = funcctx->multi_call_memory_ctx;
        oldcontext = MemoryContextSwitchTo(newcontext);

    // line1 = PG_GETARG_GEOLINESTRING_TYPE_P(0);
    // line2 = PG_GETARG_GEOLINESTRING_TYPE_P(1);

    /* allocate and zero-fill struct for persisting extracted arguments*/
    //args = palloc0(sizeof(struct line_reverse_tuple_args));

    //funcctx->user_fctx = args;

    /* total number of tuples to be returned */
    funcctx->max_calls = 3;

        /* Build a tuple descriptor for our result type */
    if (get_call_result_type(fcinfo, NULL, &tupdesc) != TYPEFUNC_COMPOSITE)
        ereport(ERROR,
                (errcode(ERRCODE_FEATURE_NOT_SUPPORTED),
                 errmsg("function returning record called in context "
                        "that cannot accept type record")));



    attinmeta = TupleDescGetAttInMetadata(tupdesc);
    funcctx->attinmeta = attinmeta;


    /* restore memory context */
    MemoryContextSwitchTo(oldcontext);

    elog(NOTICE, "geo_linestring_intersection_points_v1 end first call");

  }

  funcctx = SRF_PERCALL_SETUP();


  ct_call = funcctx->call_cntr;
  attinmeta = funcctx->attinmeta;

  elog(NOTICE, "funcapi others call");

  if (ct_call < funcctx->max_calls)
  {
    HeapTuple tuple;
    char       **values;

    /*
   * Prepare a values array for building the returned tuple.
   * This should be an array of C strings which will
   * be processed later by the type input functions.
   */
    values = (char **) palloc(3 * sizeof(char *));
    values[0] = (char *) palloc(16 * sizeof(char));
    values[1] = (char *) palloc(16 * sizeof(char));
    values[2] = (char *) palloc(16 * sizeof(char));

    snprintf(values[0], 16, "%d", 1 * PG_GETARG_INT32(1));
    snprintf(values[1], 16, "%d", 2 * PG_GETARG_INT32(1));
    snprintf(values[2], 16, "%d", 3 * PG_GETARG_INT32(1));

    /* build a tuple */
    tuple = BuildTupleFromCStrings(attinmeta, values);

    /* make the tuple into a datum */
    result = HeapTupleGetDatum(tuple);

    /* clean up (this is not really necessary) */
    pfree(values[0]);
    pfree(values[1]);
    pfree(values[2]);
    pfree(values);

    SRF_RETURN_NEXT(funcctx, result);
  }

  else
  {
    SRF_RETURN_DONE(funcctx);
  }
```

The creation of the function in sql is the same in the documentation.
But when I run an sql like this:

```
SELECT * FROM  build_rows_funcapi(1,48);
```

The server crashes. The following message appears:

> Server closed the connection unexpectedly.

Based on the elog, it is possible to observe that the function is executed until the first if: if (SRF_IS_FIRSTCALL ())

Am I implementing something wrong, or forgetting something?

Comment: common issue is using wrong memory context for returned data.

Comment: Try to [get a stack trace](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Generating_a_stack_trace_of_a_PostgreSQL_backend), that will help you figure out what went wrong and where.

Comment: Post the complete C file, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have the same postgre SQL version as the server. If not, download the correct version. If that is not the issue, check if the IP configuration in the pg_hba.conf file is set up correctly.

Comment: The server and PostgreSQL have the same version: 9.6. And the IP in pg_hba.conf is configured correctly. Thank you, but the problem still continues. The `SRF_IS_FIRSTCALL ()` function is crashing the server.